# Parse Firebase JSON array

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I need to parse the below JSON response from a Firebase Database. In this JSON sample, there are 2 documents `qouap9` and `15p3vl`. Both documents have multiple fields. I want to merge all of the fields' strings from each document to one line.

```json
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "projects/..",
      "fields": {
        "qouap9": {
          "stringValue": "A1:Hello;"
        },
        "5": {
          "stringValue": "A9:..."
        },
        "6": {
          "stringValue": "A10:..."
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2020-08-08T20:44:2",
      "updateTime": "2020-08-08T20:44:3"
    },
    {
      "name": "projects/..",
      "fields": {
        "15p3vl": {
          "stringValue": "A2:2020;"
        },
        "2": {
          "stringValue": "A6:..."
        },
        "t0w4yj": {
          "stringValue": "A4:2020;"
        },
        "1": {
          "stringValue": "A5:..."
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2020-10-20T06:58:2",
      "updateTime": "2020-10-20T06:58:2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want the result to be like this :

`A1:Hello; A9:... A10:...`

`A2:2020; A6:... A4:2020; A5:...`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the result to look like exactly?

Comment: I've made an update to the post @RemyLebeau

Comment: That is not what I asked for.  What do you want the **resulting string** to look like exactly? Are you looking for something like `'A1:Hello; A9:... A10:... A2:2020; A6:... A4:2020; A5:...'`?  Or just `'A1:Hello; A2:2020;'`? Or something else? Please be more specific. In any case, have you looked at Delphi's built-in [JSON frameworks](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON) yet?

Comment: My bad. Updated the code again. I've never used JSON framework unfortunately no. @RemyLebeau

Comment: The result you want is still unclear. `A9:... A10:...` is the fields of `documents[0]` but skipping the `qouap9` field. `A2:2020; A6:... A4:2020; A5:...` is all the fields of `documents[1]` but not skipping the `15p3vl` field.  So, why is the 1st result skipping a field? Or, did you really mean `A1:Hello; A9:... A10:...` instead?

Comment: yes i forgot the first field in `qouap9`. the idea still the same. all fields from each Documents should be in a single string. @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since last time I did not explain enough, here is another try.

```
implementation

uses
  System.JSON;

procedure DoSomeJSONStuff(const jsonstr: string);
var
  jo, fields: TJSONObject;
  ja: TJSONArray;
  jv: TJSONValue;
  i: integer;
  desiredstr: string;
begin

  // 1.
  jo := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jsonstr) as TJSONObject;
  if (jo <> nil) then begin
    try

      // 2.
      ja := jo.GetValue('documents') as TJSONArray;

      // 3.
      for jv in ja do begin
        fields := (jv as TJSONObject).GetValue('fields') as TJSONObject;
        desiredstr := '';

        // 4.
        for i := 0 to fields.Count - 1 do begin
          desiredstr := desiredstr + (fields.Pairs[i].JsonValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('stringValue').Value;
        end;
        ShowMessage(desiredstr);
      end;
    finally

      // 5.
      jo.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

1. In `jsonstr` is your JSON as a string. With `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue` you can parse your JSON and get a `TJSONValue` back if it does not fail. Otherwise the value is `nil`, hence the check for `variable <> nil`. Since `TJSONObject` is derived from `TJSONValue`, it can simply be cast explicitly in this case. Almost everything is derived from `TJSONValue` in the Delphi JSON framework. If you want to check if the `TJSONValue` is really your desired JSON container you could do it like this:

   ```
   var
    jv: TJSONValue;
    jo: TJSONObject;
   begin
     jv := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jsonstr);
     if jv is TJSONObject then begin
       jo := (jv as TJSONObject);
       // code here
     end else
       raise Exception.Create('Unexpected container - expected: TJSONObject');
   ```
2. The next step is to get the `documents` in your JSON. The value of that is an array. If you're not sure about the structure you could use `TryGetValue` instead of `GetValue`. You could check again if the returned value is actually a `TJSONArray` with `variable is TJSONArray`. I assume your structure is always the same.
3. Now we iterate through the array with a simple `for in` loop.
4. Since the element names of your `fields` do not have a "static" name we iterate through the fields by count. We get the `TJSONValue` and cast it as a `TJSONObject`. And for the `TJSONObject` we get the `stringValue`s with `GetValue('stringValue').Value` and concatenate it to the `desirestr` variable.
5. You only have to free your "main" variable/container as long as you only reference to it. Everything else is just a `Pointer`.

Edit #1: Hint about nil. Edit #2: Free memory.